# Heuristics in Graph Traversal

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to use A* to find the optimal path in a Graph.

The context is that a tourist starts at his hotel, visits landmarks and returns to his hotel at the end of the day. The nodes (landmarks) have two values: importance and time spent. Edges have two values: time spent and cost(currency).

I want to minimize cost, maximize importance and make sure total time is under a certain value. I could find a balance between cost, importance and time for the past path-cost. But what about the future cost? I know how to do it with simpler pathfinding, but is there a method I could follow to find the heuristic I need?

Comment: You won't ever find a heuristic for this which is both admissible and efficient, unless P=NP (as you could use it to solve the Knapsack Problem).

Comment: I'm more interested in it being admissable. The dimension is not going to be such efficiency becomes a serious issue. But is there an admissable heuristic to this?

Comment: A* needs all costs to be non-negative. Therefore the lowest cost solution would always be not to leave the hotel at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multi-dimensional objective (cost and importance) and so your problem is ill-posed because you haven't defined how to trade off cost and importance while you are "minimizing" cost and "maximizing" importance. You'll only get a partial ordering on sites to vist, because some pairs of sites may be incomparable because one site may have a higher cost and higher importance, while the other may have lower cost and lower importance. Look up multi-objective knapsack problem if you want concrete ways to formalize and solve your problem. And beware -- it can get a bit hairy the deeper you go into the literature.

Comment: Ok, so let's assume that I find a g(importance, cost, time) that balances out those values. What I can't wrap my head around is the h(i, c, t), on account of one thing. I only know that the total time will be under x, but how am I supposed to estimate the future cost and importance? Do I have to preprocess the graph to find something like an average value? That doesn't seem like a good estimate to aproximate but not overestimate. Those two future values are what is tripping me up.